# vite baseUrl src

Tags: vite, vitest

I'm learning vite with react and I'm having trouble to import script.

I've got a component who's importing an util function from the util folder, based in the src file

```
import { truncateText } from "utils/text/truncate";
```

but when I try to buildt this error appears

> vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "utils/text/truncate" from "src\stories\components\base\cards\product-card\productCard.component.tsx".

I put basUrl to src in the ts.config file but I suspect that I need a config more in my vite.config file.

**TS config**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["vitest/globals"],

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "vite.config.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

**vite config**

```json
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    setupFiles: ["./src/test/setup.ts"],
  },
});
```